# DateTimePicker hiding in label

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap DateTimePicker inside a label, but the picker is hidden inside the label.  I have successfully done this with a select box, but can't seem to get this to work. The DateTimePicker displays after clicking the checkbox. How do I bring this forward so it displays properly?

[Hidden DateTimePicker image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvoIa.png)

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
     <label for="enddate" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Set End Date
      <input type="checkbox" name="set_end_time" id="set_end_time">
       <input type="text" class="datetimepicker btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" name="end_time" style="display: none" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"/>
      </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: set `overflow: visible` property in the parent element. Apart that this is not enough code for debugging.

Comment: Please provide code for the datepicker. The given code does not render the output you have given as a link

Comment: overflow: visible did not work